# How do I assign a cell array to multiple matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, cell-array

I am relatively new to matlab, and I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do the following:

Given `mycellarray = {[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12] [13 14 15 16]}`, I would like to assign each matrix inside `mycellarray` to a separate variable. Is there any faster/better/shorter way to do it than this?

```
a = cell2mat(mycellarray(1,1))
b = cell2mat(mycellarray(1,2))
c = cell2mat(mycellarray(1,3))
d = cell2mat(mycellarray(1,4))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[a,b,c,d]=mycellarray{:}`

The `{:}` makes a comma seperated list of the cell array, which an be assigned to individual variables.

relevant documentation pages:

- [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)
- [comma seperated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

Comment: Thank you! I always figured that I was spending way more time than was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here a short example on how to do what you want with the MATLAB function `deal`.

```
a = {[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]}
[aa bb cc] = deal(a{:})
```

Comment: This appears to answer the question, but it could use a little more explanation.

Comment: This is currently in the Low Quality Posts queue. I'm voting not to delete, but it needs to be updated with some explanation.

Comment: This does answer the question, but deals (no pun intended) with a rather rare function: `deal`.  Please update your post with an explanation of how this works or it will inevitably be removed as it's in the Low Quality queue.